# Check whether stub getter has been called using sinon

Tags: jestjs, sinon

I'm trying to check whether a stubbed getter is being called using sinon.

I've simplified my use case as follows:

```
export class MyClass {
  public method() {
    return 5;
  }

  public get property() {
    return 5;
  }
}

it("stubs getter", () => {
    const myClass = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass);
    const stub = sinon.stub(myClass, "property").get(() => 10);
    expect(myClass.property).toBe(10); // passes
    expect(stub.called).toBe(true);    // fails
});
```

The stubbed getter is clearly working, but I can't seem to be able to verify that it has been called and I can't find anything in the documentation that can help.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/sinon-sandbox-forked-yptfl4?file=%2Ftest%2Findex.test.ts%3A10%2C36)

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense as a test - either you're spying on parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing, or you're spying on internals of a collaborator. Either way you're testing implementation details, not behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are stubbing the `get` accessor but you are spying the property itself. Said differently, the property is never called - hence `called` being false - but its getter *is* called.

You should stub the getter *and* create a spy:

```js
export class MyClass {
  public method() {
    return 5;
  }

  public get property() {
    return 5;
  }
}

it("stubs getter", () => {
    const myClass = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass);
    sinon.stub(myClass, "property").get(() => 10);

    const spiedGetter = spy(myClass, "property", ["get"]);

    expect(myClass.property).toBe(10); // passes
    expect(spiedGetter.called).toBe(true);    // works
});
```

The spies documentation of sinon explains this behaviour, although arguably not very well:

https://sinonjs.org/releases/v17/spies/

Comment: Thanks. It was a bit unexpected that I had to spy on the stub. I thought because I used `const stub = sinon.stub(myClass, "property").get(() => 10)` that the value of `stub` would actually be the getter itself and not the entire property stub but that turned out to be wrong.

Comment: I agree that it is unexepected. And the documentation is not very clear about that either. It makes sense though but really the documentation is lacking here.